# Alias checking to be disabled for jetty via jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jetty

I am using org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.5.v20120716
I just dont seem to be able to disable alias checking so the symlinks would work.
I tried:

```
<configuration>
   <systemProperties>
       <systemProperty>
          <name>checkAliases</name>
          <value>false</value>
       </systemProperty>
   </systemProperties>
 ....
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For maven jetty 9.x, the solution is 
http://www.gresw.com/blog/dev/jetty-maven-follow-symbolic-links.jsp

Comment: At that time I just forked it and allowed symlink following.

Comment: And another link only answer disappears from the Internet. Please try to not rely on a site that might be deleted.

Comment: In case I don't get to it for some reason, the maven plugin is breaking the jetty configuration (I think). I think maybe jetty is just broken.

Answer (score 2):

Check your plugin version and configuration. I'm using:

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.11.v20130520</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>checkAliases</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/testamento</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>


                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9000</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>

                <requestLog implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
                    <filename>target/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</filename>
                    <retainDays>90</retainDays>
                    <append>true</append>
                    <extended>true</extended>
                    <logTimeZone>GMT</logTimeZone>
                </requestLog>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Very thanks. This solution works in my mac. BTW, can I use `org.eclipse.jetty` here instead of `org.mortbay.jetty`?

Comment: I think for this date is more correct to use eclipse, as it is currently maintained by it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and were hoping to use Jetty as a way of quickly running a web project, but wanted to use symlinks (perhaps you want to link in something from node_modules), you can use:

```
mvn jetty:run-exploded
```

Or
    mvn jetty:run-war

However this falls short of being able to immediately reload since this works because the war plugin will correctly package everything you've linked to. It also may not be desirable based on how you want to configure your war...

The Jetty Maven Plugin instantiates a JettyWebAppContext and runs that:

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/ac24196b0d341534793308d585161381d5bca4ac/jetty-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyWebAppContext.java

see

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

As far as I can tell, there is no parameter you can pass that will allow you to call enable symlinks (you cannot pass  as you would in a jetty-web.xml, and so the alias check will always fail).

If anyone finds an answer to this (such as a github commit), please free to comment on/improve this answer.

It appears there may be a git issue to track this:
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/248